# Python Paho MQTT how to auto reconnect after Postgresql Closed connection or something else

Tags: python, django, mqtt, paho

My MQTT subscribe generally is fine, but when something exception in server, My MQTT will not working, like out of momeory then server kill postgresql or some task, and postgresql into the recovery mode, that will let mine MQTT's PostgreSQL connection fail( Connection Close) in spite of Postgresql service is back, My MQTT still connection fail(or close).

so, Is there anyway can auto reconnect?

```
import threading
import paho.mqtt.client as paho_mqtt


def t1():
    client = paho_mqtt.Client(client_id="*****")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.username_pw_set("****", "****")
    client.connect("******", ***, **)
    client.loop_forever()

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe(topic="********", qos=1)
    print('subcriptions')
    print(userdata)
    print(flags)
    print(rc)


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=t1)
thread1.start()
time.sleep(10)
thread1.join()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I find a way to resolve this problem.

```
django.db.close_old_connections()
```

when I try exception the error  ' connection already close ' then I close old connections

the Django will reconnect.

But I still testing.